# Covert flat array of objects to array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested, mapping

i'm having trouble turning a flat array to a multi nested array

```
[{
    code: "1",
    text: "FatturaElettronicaHeader",
  },
  {
    code: "1.1",
    text: "DatiTrasmissione",
  },
  {
    code: "1.1.5",
    text: "ContattiTrasmittente",
  },
  {
    code: "1.1.5.1",
    text: "Telefono",
  },
  {
    code: "1.1.5.2",
    text: "Email",
  },
  {
    code: "1.2",
    text: "CedentePrestatore",
  }
]
```

i want it so that if an array elements code includes the code of another array element, it should be a child of that element. So 1.1 and 1.2 are both children of 1. then 1.1.5 is child of 1.1 only. there should only be one of each object in the new array

Comment: its in javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can create nested tree structure using `forEach` loop to iterate through array and then for each object you can use `split` to get path array and `reduce` method to create nested structure based on the path array.

```js
const data = [{"code":"1","text":"FatturaElettronicaHeader"},{"code":"1.1","text":"DatiTrasmissione"},{"code":"1.1.5","text":"ContattiTrasmittente"},{"code":"1.1.5.1","text":"Telefono"},{"code":"1.1.5.2","text":"Email"},{"code":"1.2","text":"CedentePrestatore"}];

const result = [], level = {result}
data.forEach(e => {
  e.code.split('.').reduce((r, k) => {
    if(!r[k]) {
      r[k] = {result: []}
      r.result.push({...e, children: r[k].result})
    }
    return r[k];
  }, level)
})

console.log(result);
```

You can also use two `reduce` methods instead of `forEach` loop to get the same result.

```js
const data = [{"code":"1","text":"FatturaElettronicaHeader"},{"code":"1.1","text":"DatiTrasmissione"},{"code":"1.1.5","text":"ContattiTrasmittente"},{"code":"1.1.5.1","text":"Telefono"},{"code":"1.1.5.2","text":"Email"},{"code":"1.2","text":"CedentePrestatore"}];

const result = data.reduce((level, {code, ...rest}) => {
  return code.split('.').reduce((r, k) => {
    if(!r[k]) {
      const children = [];
      r[k] = {result: children}
      r.result.push({code, ...rest, children})
    }
    return r[k]
  }, level), level
}, {result: []}).result

console.log(result);
```